# PHP cache for a particular file

Tags: php, caching

Should be fairly simple, but there's cache involved so it never is...

I have a page that contains quite a lot of "game progress" information that may take a few seconds to load. From here the user can view various "details" pages, and may return to the "game progress" page fairly often (unless they're clever and open "details" links in new tabs :D) so in the interest of improving user experience, I want the "game progress" page to be cached by the browser for a short time - long enough that going to a progress page and coming back will reload from cache, but not so long as to risk further game completion not showing up for a while.

To this end, I added this:

```
header("Cache-Control: max-age=".(15*60));
header("Expires: ".date("r",time()+15*60);
```

And to test, I navigated to the page, proceeded to a summary view, then hit the Back button.

Expected behaviour: browser reloads the page from cache.
Observed behaviour: browser requests the page anew from the server.

Am I doing the cache headers wrong? How can I make this work?

Comment: "Should be fairly simple, but there's cache involved so it never is..." - Haha! You made my day!!

Comment: How about adding expires? mod_headers if you are serving via apache2. I have done a similar thing and adding headers will also open the site - even when the internet is down... I can browse basic pages - ofcourse at a blazing fast speed.

Comment: Just for kicks, try adding `must-revalidate` to `Cache-Control` and see if that helps

Comment: @Machavity No dice.